# Is there a way to scroll to end of page in pyppeteer

Tags: python-3.x, puppeteer, pyppeteer

I have tried looking in documentation and such, but not able to find a way to scroll down to bottom of page while using pyppeteer library with python3.

Would be great if anyone could point me to the right direction or solution.

Comment: just user hover functionality to point to your element it automatically scrolls  https://miyakogi.github.io/pyppeteer/reference.html#pyppeteer.element_handle.ElementHandle.hover

Comment: Could you provide an example to the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by doing something like this.

await page.hover(".class name")

Thanks everyone